# Spring Integration ws-outbound-gateway throwing webservicetransportexception not-found-404 error

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We are using ws-outbound-gateway to call a webservice in the following way.

```
<ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://localhost:8080/test" message-factory="messageFactory" message-sender="messageSender" ignore-empty-responses="false" requires-reply="true" />

<bean name="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
</bean>

<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
<property name="soapVersion">
 <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11"/>
 </property>
 </bean>
```

It is perfectly working fine if the request xml is in the below way.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <m:processRequest xmlns:m="http://ws.test.com">
  <request>
  <dealerId>999852</dealerId>
              .......
              .......
   </request>
 </m:processRequest>
```

If I add a **SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" and SOAP-ENV:Body** in the request xml, it is throwing the error as below:

**org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Not Found [404]**

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Not Found [404]
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:590)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:514)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:465)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:420)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:366)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:351)
        at com.railinc.notifserv.services.findusrail.impl.FindUsRailContactServiceImpl.getFindUsRailContacts(FindUsRailContactServiceImpl.java:31)
        at com.railinc.notifserv.services.findusrail.impl.FindUsRailContactServiceImplTest.testGetFindUsRailContacts(FindUsRailContactServiceImplTest.java:9)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

**Failing error xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:processRequest xmlns:m="http://ws.test.com">
    <request>
        <dealerId>999852</dealerId>
          .......
          .......
    </request>
</m:processRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to send the request xml along with soap Envelope using ws-outbound-gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I gave you an answer in the issue you have raised: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/issues/231. So, let me repeat it here!

Your problem that you have not to send a fully blown SOAP envelope into the WS Outbound Gateway. You indeed have to send just only XML for the body of the SOAP request, like you do originally.

If you really need to send the whole SOAP envelope, you need to consider to use a MimeMessage as a request payload: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ws.html#mtom-support